# How to use rails to build a restful service

Tags: rest

I want to use rails to build a restful service ?
Is there any framework to handle this ?

```
throw Exception: the remote server close the connection.
  IOException: threw IOException
```

Comment: At present, it is very unclear what you are asking.  `IOException` has very little to do with REST.

Comment: Please clarify the relation with the Exception. But outside this, Rails is a framework to creatte Restful applications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails has supported the restful service already.

Define the route like this
    resource :users

Then you will get the restful style routes with the resource users;
GET /user/:id
POST /user/:id
DELETE /user/:id
PUT /user/:id